# Log In to Website

Tags: android, http, http-post, http-get

I am making an app that needs to login to a website. To do so I make a HttpClient and perform a HttpPost to the url. This is working as far as I know. The StatusCodes give back 200. After this I perform a HttpGet to the restricted url (with the same client). However, I always get back a Forbidden Exception or the log in screen back in my LogCat. From searching on the web I found that it is sometimes needed to first perform a HttpGet to the site before the HttpPost, and also to attach a CookieStore. Done both and still no succes.. Somebody here that can help me with this?

```
        HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();

        HttpGet initiate = new HttpGet(url);            
        HttpPost post = new HttpPost(url);
        HttpGet page = new HttpGet(restrictedurl);
        HttpContext localContext = new BasicHttpContext();

        CookieStore cookieStore = new BasicCookieStore();
        localContext.setAttribute(ClientContext.COOKIE_STORE, cookieStore);

            try {
                List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", username));
                params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", password));

                post.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params, HTTP.UTF_8));

                HttpResponse response = client.execute(initiate, localContext);
                Log.i(Tag, " " + response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode());
                response.getEntity().consumeContent();

                response = client.execute(post, localContext);
                Log.i(Tag, " " + response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode());             
                response.getEntity().consumeContent();                                      

                ResponseHandler<String> handler = new BasicResponseHandler();
                String htmlpage = client.execute(page, handler, localContext);
                Log.i(Tag, " " + response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode());
                Log.i(Tag, htmlpage);
                response.getEntity().consumeContent();  

            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
```

Here is my LogCat:

```
    06-06 13:38:47.033: I/LogTag    (27839):  StatusCode HttpGet: 200
    06-06 13:38:47.197: I/LogTag    (27839):  StatusCode HttpPost: 200
    06-06 13:38:47.361: W/System.err(27839): org.apache.http.client.HttpResponseException: Forbidden
    06-06 13:38:47.377: W/System.err(27839):    at org.apache.http.impl.client.BasicResponseHandler.handleResponse(BasicResponseHandler.java:71)
    06-06 13:38:47.384: W/System.err(27839):    at org.apache.http.impl.client.BasicResponseHandler.handleResponse(BasicResponseHandler.java:59)
    06-06 13:38:47.384: W/System.err(27839):    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:657)
    06-06 13:38:47.384: W/System.err(27839):    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:627)
    06-06 13:38:47.384: W/System.err(27839):    at com.dakro.wiebetaaltwat.MainActivity$AsyncPost.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:136)
    06-06 13:38:47.384: W/System.err(27839):    at com.dakro.wiebetaaltwat.MainActivity$AsyncPost.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:1)
    06-06 13:38:47.392: W/System.err(27839):    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:264)
    06-06 13:38:47.392: W/System.err(27839):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
    06-06 13:38:47.392: W/System.err(27839):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
    06-06 13:38:47.392: W/System.err(27839):    at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:208)
    06-06 13:38:47.392: W/System.err(27839):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
    06-06 13:38:47.400: W/System.err(27839):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
    06-06 13:38:47.400: W/System.err(27839):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
```

Comment: http://www.checkupdown.com/status/E403.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sweet succes! Although I could POST to the URL and get an 200 StatusCode back it wasn't the "complete" url. Had to add index.php to it. Also the form data was not complete. Needed to add two more parameters.

```
                params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("action", "login"));
                params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("login_submit", "Inloggen"));
```

Found this out by inspecting the site for the form data it posted to the site. Used the build in Developer Tools of Chrome(Network Tab). Thanks for the responses!

Comment: When I am using postman and try to execute a POST request to http://wiebetaaltwat.nl/index.php with form data as in the chrome network tab it always links back to the default welcome page instead of actually logging in. How did you fix this?

Answer (score 1):

The forbidden error normally indicates a permissions issue on the directory/file you are accessing on the web server.

Check the owner and group permissions.  Also check the write/read/execute flags on the file.

Can you navigate directly to the url via a webbrowser and see if it is showing a forbidden message as well?

Comment: I can navigate directly to the url when I am logged in, in a browser. If I am not logged in it displays an alternative login page with a bubble saying I have to login first. 
If I change the url in the HttpGet to the main page again(which will guide me to a logged in page on my browser) it gives back the main page in a logged out setting. So it seems that I am not able to keep logged in or something through the app..

Answer (score 1):

you can use this condition

```
 StatusLine statusLine = response.getStatusLine();
                int statusCode = statusLine.getStatusCode();
                if (statusCode == 200) {

                } else {

                }
```